# Python: compare and insert a vector with an ordered numpy array

Tags: python, broadcast, array-broadcasting

I have a numpy array whose rows is ordered and a vector. I need to insert this vector into the array if the value of the vector is smaller than some values of  each array row. Furthermore, I need to get the index of the position. Can I use a vector like operation rather than two for loops?

For example, the i-th row of the array is [1,3,5,6], and the i-th value of vector is 4, the result is ([1,3,4,5], 2).
Here is the code example.

```
import random
import numpy as np

random.seed(0)
num_query = 2
topk = 3

distance = np.Inf * np.ones((num_query, topk))

print(distance)

for iter in range(4):
    print('------------loop: {:d}------------'.format(iter))
    dist = np.random.randn(num_query) / (0.3 * (iter+1))
    dist = dist * np.sign(dist)
    rows, columns = distance.shape
    for row in range(rows):
        d = dist[row]
        if d > distance[row, columns - 1]:
            continue
        min_col = 0
        for column in range(columns-1, -1, -1):
            if distance[row, column] < d:
                min_col = column + 1
                break
        distance[row, min_col + 1:] = distance[row, min_col:-1]
        distance[row, min_col] = d
    print(dist)
    print(distance)
    print('+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++')
print(distance)
```

The output is:

```
[[inf inf inf]
 [inf inf inf]]
------------loop: 0------------
[3.60155727 0.0991411 ]
[[3.60155727        inf        inf]
 [0.0991411         inf        inf]]
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
------------loop: 1------------
[1.4839764  1.99641269]
[[1.4839764  3.60155727        inf]
 [0.0991411  1.99641269        inf]]
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
------------loop: 2------------
[2.44132044 0.19221564]
[[1.4839764  2.44132044 3.60155727]
 [0.0991411  0.19221564 1.99641269]]
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
------------loop: 3------------
[0.29206705 1.17013653]
[[0.29206705 1.4839764  2.44132044]
 [0.0991411  0.19221564 1.17013653]]
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
[[0.29206705 1.4839764  2.44132044]
 [0.0991411  0.19221564 1.17013653]]
```

Comment: It looks like you hit the submit button before you finished writing your question, as is evident by there being nothing after "the output is:". If you have any additional information you'd like to include in this question, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55073961/edit) and add all relevant details.

Comment: @SupaMegaDuckyMomodaWaffle, thanks, it was an image. Now I edit it.